# Authoritative DNS for other domain requirements

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, authoritative

We're moving dns servers (managed with bind) for our main domain (let's call it main.org) to new servers. Since we're having some issues to update glue records with current registrar we thought to change authoritative dns servers to another domain (that we directly manage)

Current setup is

```
dig -t ns main.org
;; ANSWER SECTION:
main.org.       140 IN  NS  ns1.main.org.
main.org.       140 IN  NS  ns2.main.org.
```

We don't directly manage glue records for ns1.main.org and ns2.main.org, so we'd like to change in this way

```
dig -t ns main.org
;; ANSWER SECTION:
main.org.       140 IN  NS  ns1.secondary.org.
main.org.       140 IN  NS  ns2.secondary.org.
```

in order to manage better A records for ns1.secondary.org and ns2.secondary.org.

However currently s1.secondary.org and ns2.secondary.org are not authoritative dns for secondary.org zone and my registrar doesn't allow me to do the change for this reason.

Is this a strict requirement for DNS delegation?

Or in other words must ns1.secondary.org and ns2.secondary.org be authoritative for secondary.org zone in order to be authoritative also for main.org?

### More details

When I tried to insert ns1.secondary.org in the control panel for main.org (provided by registrar) I got an error saying that "ns1.secondary.org could not be added as nameserver for main.org". I opened a ticket with my reseller (it's an Enom reseller account) which in turn has forwarded the question to Enom and here is their answer:

> Enom told me that the DNS servers "ns1.secondary.org" and
>   "ns2.secondary.org" must be registered in your registrar as name
>   servers. Once you do that, either you or us can update the DNS servers
>   for the domain main.org

Comment: No, it's not necessary. Please provide the exact verbiage you received from your registrar, as you might be mis-interpreting the context of the "authority" they're discussing.

Comment: @AndrewB I've posted the answer they gave me. By reading the answer carefully I say that they don't talk about authoritative, maybe you're right... By the way I've used ns1.secondary.org as authoritative for subdomains of main.org with no issues since I manage the SOA for those subzones.